Whether we can get energy estimate $d\|X\|^2+2\|X\|_{H^1}^2 dt=2(X, B dW) +{\rm Tr}(BB^*)dt$ of a weak solution of stochastic differential equations?
I see this from, for instance:
Hairer, M., Mattingly, J.C.: Ergodicity of the 2D Navier–Stokes equations with degenerate stochastic forcing. Ann.
of Math. (2) 164 (3), 993–1032 (2006) P1027 proof of lemma A.1
https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v164-n3-p07.pdf
or
Xuhui Peng: EXPONENTIAL MIXING FOR THE FRACTIONAL MAGNETO-HYDRODYNAMIC EQUATIONS WITH DEGENERATE STOCHASTIC FORCING. COMMUNICATIONS ON doi:10.3934/cpaa.2020204 PURE AND APPLIED ANALYSIS
Volume 19, Number 9, September 2020 pp. 4479–4506 P4486 proof of lemma3.1
https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.07055
Such energy equation is essential for ergodic property of Stochastic N-S equations.
Set an probability space  $(\Omega,{\mathcal F},P)$ with filtration ${\mathcal F}_{t,t \ge 0}$, and

seperatable Hibert space $H$ and $U$
a self adjoint, sectoral，densely defined operator A on H with eigenvalue $\lambda_n \uparrow \infty$, $\lambda_n \ge 1$， eigenvector $e_n$ corresponding to $\lambda_n$, fractional space $H^s=D(A^{\frac{s}{2}})$
a U valued Q-wiener process $W(t,w)$, $U_0:=Q^{\frac{1}{2}}U$, and the space of Hibert-Schmidt operators $L^0_2=L_2(U_0,H)$
$\Phi$ an $L^0_2$ valued process stochastically integrable in $[0, T]$, $\varphi$ a $H$ valued predictable process Bochner integrable on $[0, T]$, $P$-a.s.
a function $F : [0, T ] × H → R^1$ and its partial derivatives $F_t, F_x , F_{xx}$, are uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $[0, T ] × H$.
$X(t)=X(0)+\int_0^t \varphi(s)ds +\int_0^t \Phi(s)dW(s)$ (or $dX=\varphi dt+\Phi dW$ in $H$)

Then by the $\rm It{\hat o}$ formula of infinite dimension, we have
$$
dF=F_t dt+F_x dX + \frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}(F_{xx}(\Phi Q^{\frac{1}{2}})(\Phi Q^{\frac{1}{2}})^*)dt \quad in \quad R^1
$$
If we consider a relatively simple case, where $F(x)=\|X\|_H^2=(x,x)$, and we can easily calculate its Frechet derivative $F_x(y)=2y$, $F_{xx}(y)=2I_H$(Identity mapping), for $y \in H$. $W$ a m dimension wiener process so that
$$
d\|X\|^2=2(X,\varphi) dt+ 2(X, \Phi dW) +{\rm Tr}((\Phi)(\Phi^*)dt  \quad in \quad R^1
$$
Taking into account a weak solution of a stochastic differential equation
$$
dX+AX dt= B dW
$$
where $B \in L(R^m,H)$ and the 'weak' means that for all $z \in H^1$ and $t \in [0,T]$,
$$
(X(t),z)-(X(0),z)+\int_0^t(A^{\frac{1}{2}}X(s),A^{\frac{1}{2}}z)=(BW(t),z) \quad P-a.s.
$$
Additionally, $X(\cdot) \in L^2(0,T,H^1) \cap C(0,T,H)$ P-a.s.
whether we can get the energy equation
$$
\|X(t)\|^2-\|X(0)\|^2+2\int_0^t \|A^{\frac{1}{2}}X\|^2 dt=2\int_0^t(X, B dW) +{\rm Tr}(B B^*)t
$$
by $\rm It{\hat o}$ formula?
What make difference in this situation is that the equation $dX+AX dt= B dW$ only can hold in $H^{-1}$ but not in $H$.

Minor typesetting note: $\|x\|$ (yielding $|x|$) is generally regarded as looking better than $||x||$ (yielding $||x||$). There may be some logically preferable third option that I'm not aware of; maybe someone else will chime in.

Right, that's what I'm thinking about.

But I haven't found any other more reasonable explanation.
